# некуда vs. негде: when to use which?

Tags: наречия, отрицание

Both *некуда* and *негде* mean *nowhere*, but there seems to be some semantic difference between the two. For example, we have

*Им некуда идти* **They have nowhere to go**

and

*Им негде сесть* **They have nowhere to sit**

(examples encountered in Duolingo). From these and other examples, I'm getting the feeling that *негде* is used for more specific or in some sense "smaller" locations, while the location (or rather lack thereof) in constructions using *некуда* is more abstract.

I'd like to know

1. Is there is a better way (such as a hard grammatical rule) than just developing a "feeling" to decide when to use which?
2. Are there examples where you might use either word? If yes, how do the semantics change, if at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I second other answers clarifying direction vs. location. In addition, there are some nuances regarding whether or not both words can be used.

When a verb accompanying "некуда/негде" denotes movement, both "некуда/негде" can be used (given a potentially different meaning to the whole sentence). When this verb is non-moving, only "негде" can be used.

- Им некуда идти - They have nowhere to go
- Им негде идти - They are meant to go, but there's no path
- Им негде сесть - They have no place to sit where they currently are
- Им некуда сесть - They have no place to sit even if they move around
- Им негде посидеть - They have no place to spend some time sitting
- Им некуда посидеть - WRONG. Non-movement verb!

Answer (score 7):

The difference is similar to that between *куда* and *где*: the former implies a goal or direction ("where to"), while the latter -- presence or momentary location ("where at").

*Им некуда идти* -- **They have no place where they can (or want to) go**

*Им негде сесть* --  **They have no place to sit where they currently  are**

Comment: I mostly agree with you, but it's a bit more tricky than that as `Им некуда сесть` can be as well used at least colloquially.

Answer (score 3):

From your surname, I assume you are German.  The difference is very
similar to the one between the German “*nirgendwo*” (for
“*негде*”) and “*nirgendwohin*” (for “*некуда*”):

> *Им некуда идти.* ≈ *Sie können nirgendwohin gehen.*

> *Им негде сесть.* ≈ *Sie können sich nirgendwo setzen.*

Correspondingly, “*nirgendwoher*” is “*не́откуда*”:

> *Помощи ждать неоткуда* ≈ *Hilfe wird von nirgendwoher kommen.*

**N.B.**  One must not confuse these forms and the forms with the
prefix “*ни-*”.  These forms require the particle “не”:

> *Они **не** могут никуда пойти.* ≈ *Sie können nirgendwohin gehen.*

> *Они **не** могут нигде сесть.* ≈ *Sie können sich nirgendwo setzen.*

> *Помощь **не** придёт ниоткуда.* ≈ *Hilfe wird von nirgendwoher kommen.*